# Html external function calling

Tags: javascript, html

I have two files in html namely example and add-activity. I have a function in example and I want to call it from add-activity such that even my example file is updated. I already tried everything i could but no luck. How can i do that? Please help
example.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function displayResult()
{
var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
var row=table.insertRow(0);
var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
cell1.innerHTML=document.getElementById('txtact').value;
cell2.innerHTML=document.getElementById('txtcat').value;
cell3.innerHTML=document.getElementById('datetime').value;
cell4.innerHTML=document.getElementById('datetime1').value;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Username: <input type="text" name="txtname"><br>
Branch: <input type="text" name="txtbranch"><br>
<table style="border:1px solid black;" cellpadding="-2">
<tr>
<th width="70%" bgcolor="#D8E4BC">Activity</th>
<th><button type="button" onclick="location.href='add-activity.html'">Add</button>
</th>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="myTable" border="1" width="33.69%">
  <tr>
    <td>Coll Activity</td>
    <td>category</td>
     <td>From</td>
      <td>To</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<button type="submit" onclick="location.href='submit.html'">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

add-activity.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add activity</title>
<style type="text/css">
 button {
    width: 10em;
    padding: -2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999; 
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #bbb;
    background-color: #7F98E5;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#e9ede8), to(#7F98E5),color-stop(0.6, #1947D1));
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<b><font face="verdana" size="4">
<table style="border:1px solid black;">
<tr>
<td width="43%" bgcolor="#D8E4BC">Add Activity</td>
</tr>
</table>
</font>
<br>
<br>
<form>
Activity: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Activity..." size="33" id="txtact" name="txtact"><br>
Category: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Category..." size="33" id="txtcat" name="txtcat"><br>
Duration:<br><br>
From: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="time" name="usrtime" id="usrtime"><br>
To: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="time" name="usrtime1" id="usrtime1"><br><br>
</form>
<button type="button" class="button">Add</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="location.href='example.html'">Cancel</button>
</b>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post that function and how you are calling them?

Comment: Are you using iframes? If not, your best bet is to remove the js code and put it in a seperate ".js" file and include that file on each page.

Comment: I have a table in my example file and i want to update that table by user input in add-activity file. My add-activity file have some fields and add button when i enter the field values and click add button it should update my table in example file by those values

Answer (score 0):

try to add that java script function in external file and add it in header using  tag and call it in example and add-activity file

Comment: I have a table in my example file and i want to update that table by user input in add-activity file. My add-activity file have some fields and add button when i enter the field values and click add button it should update my table in example file by those values

Comment: i think you are very newbie to scripting ,your code look like you are learning , any how give your exact requirement with clear explanation

Comment: sorry for late reply but yes i'm a newbie and i want that when i click add activity button from example file it should open add-activity file and when i write all data and click on add, the add-activity file should close and that data should be seen as a table in example file. So i can keep adding activity or delete it as well from table